# Python's decimal module and the table maker's dilemma

Tags: python, numeric

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), the .exp() operation in

Python's decimal module "is correctly rounded using  ...".

Because of the [table maker's dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#The_table-maker.27s_dilemma), I hope that's not guaranteed, since I'd prefer a guarantee

that it's computation on a normal-looking input with moderately low precision won't take, eg., a year.

How does Python address this?

(Is it different between versions?)

Comment: So you'd be happy with a wrong answer faster?

Comment: If you don't need exact rounding and do need performance, you probably shouldn't be using the `Decimal` type, since radix-10 computations are much slower than radix-2 on modern hardware.  Stick with Python's `float` type, or if 56 bits is not enough, head first to things like MPFR/bigfloat.

Comment: The performance I'm interested in here is "bound[ing] the worst case computation time with a sensible value", as that paper calls it.  I would think it should allow choosing a (not too large) k and then just having a guarantee that the rounded result is less than (0.5+(10^(-k)))*unit_in_the_last_place away from the true result.

Answer (score 3):

The `exp()` and `pow()` functions are different.

The "table-maker's dilemma" explanation you link to states that x<sup>y</sup> cannot be correctly rounded by any known algorithm with a bounded amount of time.  However, this is obviously not the case for all subsets of its domain.  If we restrict the domain to x=3 and y=2, then I can tell you what the correctly-rounded answer is.

A quick Google search turns up *Correctly-Rounded Exponential Function in Double-Precision Arithmetic,* by David Defour, Florent de Dinechin, Jean-Michel Muller ([CiteSeer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.4069), [PDF](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/23/87/PDF/RR-4231.pdf)).  The article provides an algorithm for computing a correctly-rounded `exp()` and provides the worst-case bound on its running time.

This is not the radix=10 case, but it shows how the table-maker's dilemma does not necessarily apply to the `exp()` function.